# How to localization things in the same line

Tags: php, html, css

im working on homepage of my web site like google. in the center one textbox for the search task, and search buton near it ,  but i have many problem with localization. firstly, i have words top of my web site and i want to locate in different places in same line . left and right. for example language options like DE / FR on the left, Login / Help on the right in the same line.  to the right , i tried with this;

```
 #right
{   
    position:relative;
    top:10% ;
    left:61%;
    margin-right:10px;
}



<a href="login.php" id="right" >Login</a>
```

when i do this, its look like i want but  when i make page smaller whole content messed up include search buton. And finally i tried to position button near the textbox like i said but i couldnt. i mean i have a problem position  same lane things.. i looked here about my question but cant find exactly similar to mine, ty.

Comment: It sounds to me that your issue is not directly related to HTML or PHP code, but to the responsiveness of your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/gbuLykdj/3/
Just make you container display as table, and the content as a table cell. That will allow you to vertically center your elements

```
 <div class='container'>
      <section><input type="text" placeholder="search"><button>search</button></section>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:arial;
}

.container{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

section{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: first of all , thank you for your answer. i tried what you said and it worked, but, as i asked my question i need to add some link on top- left and top-right of the page. but when i add , textbox and button are shifted. as if im adding other components to another column.